# The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed error, need assistance

Tags: java, sql-server

Full error I'm getting:

The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

I have already checked that TCP/IP is enabled, using port 1433, and TCP dynamic ports is empty. I have disabled windows firewall.

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnect {




public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=TestDB1;instance=SQLSERVER;encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;";
    String user = "sa";
    String pass = "";
    try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    
    
    Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
    try {
    Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
    
    try {
    ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("Select * from Login");
    
    
    
        while (myRs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("Username"));
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("Password"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error with query");
    }
    }
    
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error connecting to database");
    }
    }
    
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have you done all of the things that are suggested by the error message?  All of them?  Have you actually verified that the server is >>listening<< on 127.0.0.1:1433?

Comment: @xralf how quickly do you get the error? immediately or few seconds?

Comment: @SalmanA few seconds

Comment: @xralf if you're sure that port 1433 is open then check if the instance name is correct. Usually it is `mssqlserver` (in which case you can remove it). If you specified instance name incorrectly in connection string you'll get some kind of error but it might be indistinguishable from a general port blocked/tcpip disabled/similar error.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Have you enabled 'Named Pipes' and 'TCP/IP'?**

1. Open the 'Sql Server Configuration Manager' application.
2. In the left pane, go to 'SQL Server Network Configuration' -> 'Protocols for [instance-name]'
3. Right-click on both 'Named Pipes' and 'TCP/IP' and select 'enable'.

**Have you used the correct port?**

4. Double-click on 'TCP/IP'
5. Select 'IP Addresses' tab
6. Scroll to IPAII. Your port number is here.

---

7. Restart the 'SQL Server ([instance-name])' windows service.

Comment: I didn't enable named pipes, thank you, that fixed it

Comment: Should I change the IPAII port number?

Comment: Re-starting SQL Server Service after the changes is very important.

Comment: live saver thanks a lot!

Comment: This saved me from having a mental breakdown, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This error usually come when SQL server not accepting TCP/IP Connection, pls try below steps it will work for sure.

1)open run and add command SQLServerManager15.msc
2)click on network configuration then "protocols for MSSQLSERVER"
3)Select protocol name - "TCP\IP" and make sure that it is enable if not then pls make it enable.
4)Check the property and find port in IP address tab.

Restart the server, it should work

Answer (score 1):

My solution:
Client: DBeaver
Auth: Windows Authentication

After taking the steps:

- Enable tcp/ip
- Enabling named pipes

Connection string: localhost\SQLEXPRESS (that backslash made all the difference).

Answer (score 1):

I look at the `ERRORLOG` file for troubleshooting information. This file is *usually* located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL<nn>.<instance name>\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
```

The `<nn>` is the [SQL Server version number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/download-and-install-latest-updates) and `<instance name>` is the instance name. The file contains useful information in the beginning:

```
2023-04-01 11:11:44.15 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3156.0 (X64) 
    May  4 2015 18:48:09 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

.
.
.
2023-04-01 11:11:44.16 Server      Server process ID is 4668.
.
.
.
2023-04-01 11:11:44.16 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -s "SQLSERVER_INSTANCE_2"
.
.
.
2023-04-01 11:11:45.12 spid4s      Server name is 'SQLMACHINE1\SQLSERVER_INSTANCE_2'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
.
.
.
2023-04-01 11:11:45.16 spid10s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433].
2023-04-01 11:11:45.16 spid10s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].
2023-04-01 11:11:45.16 spid10s     Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQLSERVER_INSTANCE_2 ].
2023-04-01 11:11:45.16 spid10s     Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\MSSQL$SQLSERVER_INSTANCE_2\sql\query ].
.
.
.
```

From the above you should be able to find out the following information about the SQL Server instance:

- Start up date and time
- Version
- Process ID
- Instance Name (MSSQLSERVER for the default instance)
- IP and port number (if TCP/IP protocol is enabled, 1433 is the default port)
- Named pipe path (even if named pipe protocol is disabled)

Once you have this information, [build the connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

Default values are used for unspecified url components. Make sure to escape `\` inside string literals.

Note that when using instance name without port number, a request is made to [SQL Server browser service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-browser-service?view=sql-server-ver16). That, too, needs to be running and UDP port 1434 must be open.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it tomorrow. It's interesting that SQLApp works (and RemoDB and my app doesn't work). I remember that in SQLApp the port wasn't specified.

Comment: Server name must be specified. Not specifying instance name -> default instance is assumed, not specifying port -> 1433 is assumed.

Comment: I added instance name and it writes now [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766114/sql-server-jdbc-error-on-java-8-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connect) error message. I already added ";encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;" but didn't help.

Comment: Unfortunately this could be or many reasons... outdated driver, outdated sql server, disabled ssl protocols and more. Try with `encrypt=false`. This will disable encryption thus no ssl issues.

Comment: I had to use the jtds driver and with instance parameter it works. For microsoft driver I created a new bounty. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

And also make sure that on the same page TCP/IP is enabled

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue was that I was using the wrong IP address. Especially since it's saying the connection timed out, it seems like that IP address doesn't work. Open up terminal and run "ipconfig" and see which IP is IPv4, that's the one you want to use.