# JDBC SSL connection issue

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, jdbc, jsse

We have a JEE based web application and it was running for years without any problems. We use jdk 1.7 and tomcat 6 with mssql 2008 as The DB and sqljdbc-1.2.jar as the JDBC driver. Recently we stared using SpagoBi tool for custom reporting and we installed it as a separate installation, but shared the same mssql database. Then we observed following error on our log files and the system started crashing once in a while. As a workaround we restart the the server every weekend now.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed..
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.throwSSLConnectionFailed(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.loginWithoutFailover(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
```

According to my readings this could happen due to the old jdbc driver that we are using. but the problem is, it is not happening regularly.But if it happens it will continuously throwing this error.

Do you guys have any idea about this?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766114/sql-server-jdbc-error-on-java-8-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connect) question and the accepted answer should definitely help you!

Comment: sqljdbc 1.2 is ancient, you might want to try a newer version.

Comment: Sharing answer from other issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/43240694/2995001