# Azure Sql Server and Hibernate Java Mac

Tags: java, macos, hibernate, azure

I have Eclipse and Hibernate that connect to Azure Sql Server (Microsoft Azure for Students). I uploaded to a git the project that works perfectly on the school pc with Windows but here on my Mac can not connect to server ... The only difference is the Hibernate Library & JDBC library, the code it's the same. :(

## output:

```
Jan 11, 2017 4:03:51 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.3.Final}
Jan 11, 2017 4:03:51 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jan 11, 2017 4:03:51 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jan 11, 2017 4:03:52 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Jan 11, 2017 4:03:52 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Jan 11, 2017 4:03:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jan 11, 2017 4:03:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at URL [jdbc:sqlserver://usedproy.database.windows.net:1433;database=used;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;]
Jan 11, 2017 4:03:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=usuario@usedproy, password=****}
Jan 11, 2017 4:03:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jan 11, 2017 4:03:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at probandohibernate.PersonFactory.<clinit>(PersonFactory.java:31)
    at probandohibernate.ProbandoHibernate.insert(ProbandoHibernate.java:55)
    at probandohibernate.ProbandoHibernate.main(ProbandoHibernate.java:23)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:c2231f63-42b7-473b-8cab-e16e8473cb31
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1654)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:4844)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6154)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6106)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2907)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 30 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at probandohibernate.ProbandoHibernate.insert(ProbandoHibernate.java:82)
    at probandohibernate.ProbandoHibernate.main(ProbandoHibernate.java:23)
```

## Hibernate conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="Hibernate">
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://***.database.windows.net:1433;database=****;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">***@***</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">***</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <mapping class="probandohibernate.modelo.Empleados"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

## Java Class:

```
package probandohibernate.modelo;

/**
 *
 * @author leo
 */

import java.sql.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;
/**
 *
 * @author John
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "Empleados")
public class Empleados {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY) //Editado
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "Nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name = "Apellidos")
    private String apellido;
    @Column(name = "FechaNacimiento")
    private Date fechaNacimiento;
    @Column(name = "Movil")
    private String movil;

    public Empleados() {
    }

    public Empleados(String nombre, String apellido, Date fechaNacimiento, String movil) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
        this.movil = movil;

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public Date getFechaNacimiento() {
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public String getMovil() {
        return movil;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimiento(Date fechaNacimiento) {
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setMovil(String movil) {
        this.movil = movil;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Empleado [id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", apellido=" + apellido + ", fechaNacimiento="
                + fechaNacimiento + ", movil=" + movil + "]";
    }



}
```

## Hibernate Class:

```
package probandohibernate;

/**
 *
 * @author leo
 */
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import probandohibernate.modelo.Empleados;

public class PersonFactory {
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
Configuration configuration=new Configuration()
            .configure(); // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Empleados.class);

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

    // If you miss the below line then it will complaing about a missing dialect setting
    serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

    serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}

 private static void read(){
          Session session = null;
          try {
              try {

                sessionFactory = PersonFactory.getSessionFactory();
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<Empleados> list = session.createQuery("from Empleados")
                        .list();

                for (Empleados p : list)
                    System.out.println(p);


              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          } finally {
              session.close();
          }
    }
```

## Libraries:

[image: Libraries I use]

## Update:

I just disabled the firewall of Sierra and of Avast and a get this Exception.

```
Jan 13, 2017 12:40:54 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
Jan 13, 2017 12:40:54 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jan 13, 2017 12:40:54 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jan 13, 2017 12:40:54 AM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Jan 13, 2017 12:40:54 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Jan 13, 2017 12:40:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jan 13, 2017 12:40:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at URL [jdbc:sqlserver://usedproy.database.windows.net:1433;database=used;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;]
Jan 13, 2017 12:40:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=usuario@usedproy, password=****}
Jan 13, 2017 12:40:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jan 13, 2017 12:40:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at probandohibernate.PersonFactory.<clinit>(PersonFactory.java:34)
    at probandohibernate.ProbandoHibernate.insert(ProbandoHibernate.java:65)
    at probandohibernate.ProbandoHibernate.main(ProbandoHibernate.java:30)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset ClientConnectionId:93c921a0-b8bf-48fe-b3da-0064cc309d63
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1654)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1789)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:4838)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6154)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6106)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2907)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 30 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at probandohibernate.ProbandoHibernate.insert(ProbandoHibernate.java:92)
    at probandohibernate.ProbandoHibernate.main(ProbandoHibernate.java:30)
```

## - More info:

If help something with JDBC doesn't work too

**Code of JDBC:**

```
package es.iesnervion.model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MakingStatement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            // Carga el driver
            try {

              // Carga la clase del driver
              Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

              // Define the data source for the driver
              String sourceURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://******.database.windows.net:1433;database=***;user=***@usedproy;password=****;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
              String miSelect = "SELECT ID, Nombre FROM Empleados";

              // Crear una connexi�n con el DriverManager
              Connection connexionBaseDatos = 
                DriverManager.getConnection(sourceURL);
              Statement sentencia = connexionBaseDatos.createStatement();
              ResultSet nombresProductos = sentencia.executeQuery(miSelect);

              // Mostrar los datos del ResultSet
              System.out.println("Productos                          ->  PVP");
              System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
              while (nombresProductos.next())
                  System.out.println(nombresProductos.getString("Nombre")+ " -> " + 
                    nombresProductos.getInt("ID"));

              // Cerrar conexi�n
                  connexionBaseDatos.close();
            } 
              catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
              System.err.println(cnfe);
            } 
              catch (SQLException sqle) {
              sqle.printStackTrace();
            } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the DB maybe somehow configured to only accept requests from your schools IP, so it does not answer when you try to connect from home? Or do you have some firewall at home that blocks the access to port 1433 outbound?

Comment: The DB have a firewall with a withelist ip but the ip of my home and the school is introduced. I can connect to DB with Visual Studio Code so I can effectuate connection. :/

Comment: @AdriánPol What are the differences of Hibernate & JDBC libraries between your school Windows PC and your Mac? Is it version different? Or others, such as using jTDS at Windows, using MSSQL JDBC at Mac?

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT I have brought the project with all the libraries I use on the school pc and I get the same result, I can not connect, I think the operating system is the guilty.

Comment: @AdriánPol Sorry for not reproducing the issue directly on my linux environment. But I'm not sure that the issue was caused by MacOS. Could you try to connect SQL Azure via only using JDBC(MSSQL Driver or jTDS) APIs? I want to know whether Hibernet or other possible incompatible libraries casue the issue. Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Don't worry @PeterPan-MSFT :) Very good idea, this morning I'll try that, it has a lot logic, thank you so much :)

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT It doesn't work with JDBC neither :( output this error `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:id_client_connection `

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, the issue seems to be the same as the SO thread [SQL Server JDBC Error on Java 8: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766114/sql-server-jdbc-error-on-java-8-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connect), please follow the answer for the existing SO thread & the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for properties configuration of connection string to try to solve it. Any update, please feel free to let me know.