# The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer work on java 1.8.0_161 however not on 1.8.0_202

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jdbc, sqljdbc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server in my spring boot application. However, I get below error on Java version 1.8.0_202. I am able to successfully make connection with Java 1.8.0_161. What can be the reason for this?

Jar used - sqljdbc42.jar, also tried sqljdbc4.jar as well as mysqljdbc7.2.1.jre8.jar.

**SQL Server -** Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3239.00 (Intel X86)

**Connection String**

`jdbc:sqlserver://*ServerIP*:*Serverport*;databaseName=*dbname*;encrypt=false;sslProtocol=TLSv1;user=*user*;password=*******;`

**Stacktrace**

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:e5acda6c-b947-447d-bc81-17322f798b6e".
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:600)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:657)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:688)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:751)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:e5acda6c-b947-447d-bc81-17322f798b6e".
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2399)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1762)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1976)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1627)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1458)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:772)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:704)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnection(SQLServerDataSource.java:54)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:e5acda6c-b947-447d-bc81-17322f798b6e
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:711)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:768)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:760)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:955)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:943)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1688)
        ... 35 more
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the SQL Server version you are using, and the full exception stacktrace. AFAIK, between Java 8 update 161 and update 202, a number of old SSL ciphers and protocol versions have been disabled by default. Also, have you tried **removing** the `sslProtocol=TLSv1` from the URL? You are forcing a specific (and old) protocol version, which could be part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just updated the original post with complete stack trace. Yes i did try without `sslProtocol=TLSv1` and had the same issue. SQL Server version is 2005. Added details in post as well.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 is pretty old by now, you may want to scan the Java release notes for disabled TLS cipher suites algorithms, TLS versions etc. And maybe enable SSL/JCE debugging to see if it gives more information to track this down. I'm not really an expert on that though, so apart from giving general pointers, I can't be of much help. Maybe someone else comes by that knows more on this topic.

Comment: Maybe this question will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766114/sql-server-jdbc-error-on-java-8-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connect (might be a duplicate of your question).