# Why am I getting "The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server" when running the jar but not when running the project in maven?

Tags: java, sql-server, maven

I have a Java project that connects to SQL Server using mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar.  When I run the project using "mvn exec:java" the code works just fine.  But when I build the project into a jar using "mvn clean compile package" and copy the jdbc jar into the target directory and then try running using "java -jar "  I get the error

```
ERROR connecting to SQL Server: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.
```

Why does it work when not jarred, but doesn't work when jarred?

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766114/sql-server-jdbc-error-on-java-8-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connect

Comment: Thanks.  That's showing the output in Linux but I'm working in Windows and don't find TSLV in the output of my job.  Is there something parallel I should be looking at?