# In Jmeter Unable to make JDBC Connection to SSMS getting Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to make a JDBC connection to SQL server but I am getting this error
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:ed21ad88-5a8b-47fc-837e-e93b3caf2fca".)

using SSMS (SQL server 18) using java version "18.0.1.1"

I checked in related content in stackoverflow but still no use
[SQL Server JDBC Error on Java 8: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766114/sql-server-jdbc-error-on-java-8-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connect)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qImFG.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrafO.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with [SSL handshake](https://www.ssl.com/article/ssl-tls-handshake-overview/) between the JDBC driver and MSSQL database, you can [enable SSL debugging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) by adding the next line to [*system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

As a workaround you can add `encrypt=false` parameter to your [JDBC URL](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc-url-format) so the connection would be plaintext, the error should go away, however if you're testing the database your setup should be as close to the production as possible so I would rather recommend checking out what's going on with the secure communications.

Comment: Thanks @dmitri , Issue is resolved when I follow this jdbc:sqlserver://XXX:1433;instanceName=XXXX;DatabaseName=XXXX;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;sslProtocol=TLSv1.2 but now I get this error - java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory